# Generic looping directive, does one exist?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

We have some data that looks like this:

`[{id: 1, link: "foo"}, {id: 2, link: "bar"}, ..., {id:n, link:"nth"}]`

And we want to generate some output like this:

```
<ul>
<li>id is: 1</li>
<li>link is: "foo"</li>
<li>id is: 2</li>
<li>link is: "bar"</li>
...
<li>id is: n</li>
<li>link is: "n"</li>
</ul>
```

It is a case where at first blush we figured we would write a
directive named 'menuitem' that would emit the contents

```
<li>id is: 1</li>
<li>link is: "foo"</li>
```

And we could do something like `<menuitem ngrepeat="item in
items"></menuitem>`, so we could do it the NG way of a custom directive
and then use the standard ngrepeat functionality. Staring at it for a
while it seemed though like we ought to just generalize it so that we
could define a custom directive like functionality as needed more
like:

```
<ng-repeater ngrepeat="item in items">
  <li>id is: {{item.id}}</li>
  <li>link is: "{{item.link}}"</li>
</ng-repeater>
```

Then we wondered, does something like this exist already, somewhere?
Because... I bet we are not the first to want to do something like
this.

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some new functionality coming down the pipe that will handle this situation, but I don't think it's been released in a new build yet:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2

```
It is now possible to iterate over multiple elements like so:

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in list">I get repeated</tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end>I also get repeated</tr>
</table>
```